# App Inventor 2 - Image changes after time

Tags: android, app-inventor

I need to make it so that the image changes automatically to another image after around 27 seconds in correlation to a sound file.
I'm using **App Inventor 2** to do this, I'm also a noob when it comes to this type of thing.

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant piece of code to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then *edit* your question and add a screenshot of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
XML code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Count"
    android:textColor="#F44336"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="168dp" />
```

And Activity:

```
private ImageSwitcher sw;
private TextView tv1;
CountDownTimer myCountDown;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    sw = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
    sw.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            ImageView myView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            return myView;
        }
    });
    sw.setImageResource(R.drawable.love1);

    myCountDown =  new CountDownTimer(27000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv1.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv1.setText("0");
            sw.setImageResource(R.drawable.love2);
        }
    };
    myCountDown.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use Clock component. You can find it in sensors part. Just drag it into your screen. Secondly, just make a global list of images that you want to view during the sound is playing.

Then, just make a global integer variables for the time countdown and images index. You just need to set time variable to "27" and images index variable to "0" when the sound button is clicked.

Then, add a check to detect the countdown variable. Just see below image for full code:

[image]

Lastly, you need to set the countdown variable to "0" when to sound is end. You also can set the canvas visible to false to hide the image.